# We are hoping ( for?) a good monsoon this year

Tags: prepositions

> We are **hoping** a good monsoon this year

Is the above sentence correct ? Actually this is a sentence improvement question and actual sentence was *We are **expecting** a good monsoon this year.* My book replaced *expecting* with *hoping* but don't we need to use preposition *for* with hoping in above sentence ? Or it's all right to use it without preposition ?

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER : NO. The above-mentioned usage is incorrect.

REASON: The infinite forms of both verbs are as follows:

To Expect

To Hope

And it's easy to mistake that the same modification to the verb would yield the same meaning. But English is a tricky language.
And hope cannot exist without specifying what one is waiting eagerly for to happen.

"We are expecting a monsoon this year" means that the people are waiting for it to rain, based on a previous prediction or calculation.

"We are hoping for a monsoon this year" means that people are waiting for it to rain, but it isn't clear whether or not it is based off of a previous prediction or calculation.

And in that regards, we can't replace "expecting" with "hoping for" without the meaning changing, but I guess you may use it if you please.

Comment: Your answer is NO for what ? I have asked two questions in the thread.

Comment: I answer NO to the first and last question used by you, namely "IIs the above sentence correct ?" and "Or it's all right to use it without preposition ?"